# cargar un dropdownlist con una variable razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlist

Hola tengo una clase entradas que tiene una propiedad cantidad(int), quiero cargar un dropdownlist con el valor de esa propiedad, ej: si cantidad vale 10, cuando despliegue me tiene que mostrar 1,2,3..9,10 se entiende?

estoy trabajando en visualstudio proyecto c# asp.net mvc

desde ya muchas gracias, espero puedan ayudarme. Saludos

Comment: Saludos Jose, revisa este workshop sobre aspnet mvc, te será de utiidad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Answer (score 0):

Intenta generando un array de la secuencia con [`Enumerable.Range()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8) y luego imprimes cada numero utilizando un `foreach`:

```
<select>
    @foreach(var secuencia in Enumerable.Range(1, Model.Cantidad))
    {
        <option value="@secuencia">@secuencia</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: muchas gracias! me sirvio..ahora me gustaria saber como capturar ese valor..espero puedas ayudarme..